# Update Codeigniter's data on Table #2 based Table #1's id

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 tables, **reservation** and is **customer**

```
table #1 : reservation
------------------------
- reservation_id
- reservation_status
- customer_id

table #2 : customer
------------------------
- customer_id
- customer_name
- customer_status
```

I'm new in codeigniter but how I can update/change `customer status` (from 0 to 1 or 1 to somevalue) based on `reservation id`

is there using join and update or somewhat.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE customer AS C JOIN reservation AS R ON R.customer_id=C.customer_id 
SET C.customer_status = (CASE C.customer_status WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
WHERE R.reservation_id="2"';
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
if($result) {
   echo "Success";
} else {
   echo "fail";
}
```

And check your query by:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UPDATE customer
        JOIN reservation
        ON customer.customer_id = reservation.customer_id
SET     customer.customer_status = your_value;
WHERE   reservation.reservation_id="your_id"';
```